# What event Asus Transformer calls in Android, then docking or undocking the tablet?

Tags: android

I have problems with my app on Asus Transformer TF101, with keyboard.

If i dock it to keyboard (or undock it) during displaying a activity, 
the activity is recreated.
That means:
onDestroy is called.
onCreate is called.

Is it possible to catch the event that user is undocking or docking?

Comment: please learn the android activity lifecycle. When the configuration changes, the activity is destroyed and recreated and YOU have to implement correctly the save/resume callback methods provided by the operating system

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:configChanges="keyboard"` to your activity. See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/docking-monitoring.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) for how runtime changes work with regards to Activities.

On the other hand, if it's operating like a phone dock, then try listening for `ACTION_DOCK_EVENT`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/docking-monitoring.html) for a tutorial. This would not explain why the activity is being recreated, though, while the above does.